# Fullscreen apps on linux multi monitor setups

Tags: linux, screen-resolution, monitors

Whats the best / easiest way to prevent full screen apps in linux from spanning all monitors.  In windows a full screen app will only take over 1 monitor.

I'm using the Nvidia drivers with Twinview

Comment: Let us know which distro/window manager you are using. It could be you just need to configure your WM to handle each xinerama screen separately instead of as a continuous canvas.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your graphics setup and your window manager.

For example, I use an nvidia card with 2 outputs. Using the nvidia config utility I can specify the screen layout, which gives me 2 xinerama screens. Nvidia call this facility TwinView.

xmonad is my window manager which can handle multiple screens quite easily. All modern WMs should handle this correctly.

Comment: I have the same nvidia setup with the manufacturer nvidia driver, xinerama running Fedora 10 & Gnome right now.  It can span both windows, but it "sticks" in each monitor for a split second.  When I maximize a window, it only maximizes to *one* screen

Comment: I have used IceWM and Xmonad with this setup and they both maximise a window to the current physical screen, unless you resize it manually to use the full double screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is usually dependent on your window manager. In WindowMaker, this doesn't happen unless the app figures out the resolution itself and then changes window size to that, as opposed to letting the window manager handle that itself.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine on Debian/Ubuntu with the nVidia drivers. You have given us very little info but I think I remember having this problem with ATI drivers a while back.